# Is string matching and replacement considered in formal languages?

Tags: formal-languages, strings

Is string matching and replacement, as an operation on strings or on formal languages, considered in  formal languages?

1. For example, the family of regular languages, or the family of
   context free languages, ..., are closed under certain string
   operations.

   I would wonder if these families or some others may be closed under
   string matching and replacement?
2. Are string matching and replacement equivalent to some combination
   of other string operations?
3. Or is matching and replacement considered in formal languages in
   some other ways?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: To clarify. If I have a string `abbb` and replace `ab` with `ba`, do I end up with `babb` or `bbba`?

Comment: As an operation on strings, either is fine, As an operation on languages, it seems natural to me that matching and replacement can be applied arbitrarily many times.

Comment: If replacing is not iterated, I suspect that everything is closed under it. If replacing is iterated, regular `bcbcbc` can be easily turned into `bbbccc` and context free `aaabcbcbc` can be turned into context  sensitive `aaabbbccc`. If several rewriting rules can be iterated, all RE languages can be generated, but if it's just one, then I'm not sure.

Comment: Technically, it seems like "string matching" is exactly the problem solved by automata. Replacement seems like a special case of the problem transducers solve, i.e., reading input and emitting output.

Answer (score 4):

Match & replace is a special case of [rational transduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer), a quite powerful class of string mappings with [a number of nice properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer#Operations_on_finite_state_transducers).

The classes of regular, context-free and recursive enumerable languages are all closed against rational transduction ([source](http://planetmath.org/closurepropertiesonlanguages)), so this carries over to match & replace.

[It does not seem](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/12921/98) as if the necessary elementary operations had a representation in formal language theory.

Comment: FYI: Classes closed under finite state transductions are called "full trio" or "[cone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cone_%28formal_languages%29)".

Answer (score 3):

Well, basically the application of a production by a grammar *is* find & replace. So string matching and replacement is part of type-0 grammars, at the heart of formal languages. Iterated replacement is computing.

Or is that too simple?

Comment: I have never viewed the act of applying a grammar rule as search & replace. Maybe because, to me, a grammar is a declarative object whereas search & replace is an operational object (a procedure/algorithm).